# 2011 Ford Mustang Gt "Check Charging System" light after changing alternator

Tags: electrical, battery, alternator, charging, warning-light

My mustang started showing a code for "camshaft position sensor" so I replaced it.

1 day later, it came back on, same sensor so I started doing research. Everything I read said it was probably the alternator, so I replaced it. Started it up, took it down the road and the "Check Charging System" light came on....this one was new.

I thought ok, maybe I got a bad alternator so I went and had it tested, alternator was good. Put it back in, crossed all my "t's", dotted all my "I's" and got it back together. Same thing, get down the road the charging light comes back on.

Off thing is, it comes on and off within maybe 20 seconds,  it doesn't constantly stay on at first. It could be the battery? Wiring? A fuse? Just odd how that light shows up that wasn't there before. Any ideas?

Comment: Check your fuses.

Comment: Sounds likely to be a poor connection somewhere. Pehaps the terminals inside the connector for either alternator or pcm.

Comment: Intermittent in the alternator connector. Check for loose terminals or open in the wiring harness to the alt